# Is there a Internet PC Parts database? Like IMDB except it's about PC parts: motherboards, CPUs, Power supplies etc etc

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, database

I would love to have a central place where information about all PC parts are kept. Even better if the whole database can be downloaded as CSV and analysed using R or SAS.

Comment: there are several that try's to do it for CPU's but not all the other parts, unfortunately the name and url of the one I think is best currently eludes me

Comment: I don't think the vendors would like it if someone displayed there versioning of hardware increments (with prices to make it worse), plus there are so many vendors that all PC parts is a little too general. I would love to have it though!

Comment: @ianfuture: I keep running across http://www.cpu-world.com, not sure how that compares to the others.

Comment: https://pcpartpicker.com might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

If you're comfortable scripting, it wouldn't be hard to crawl NCIX, NewEgg, or your site de jour with WWW::Mechanize (or its equivalent), but I can't exactly recommend it, ethically.

Answer (score 2):

While not exhaustive, or necessarily that up-to-date you might find [wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org) a useful source. I've especially found the following pages useful, though there must be similar pages for other components:

- List of Intel Core 2 microprocessors
- List of Intel Pentium Dual-Core microprocessors
- List of Intel Pentium microprocessors

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [Red Hill Guide to Computer Hardware](http://www.redhill.net.au/ig.html) interesting even though it really hasn't been updated since 2002-2003 or so.  Has a lot of fascinating information (and opinions) on 80's and 90's era hardware and hard drives, however, and defintely worth looking at if you want a good history of PC hardware.

No user reviews, though. :(

Answer (score -1):

If you are too database centric for your own purpose; have a look at: [SQL computer hardware database](http://www.techytalk.info/other-projects/sql-computer-hardware-database/)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers, as they tend to get out of date, or could go down at any time. Instead, post the information from the link, and add the link as a citation or reference for your answer.

Comment: Well, @CanadianLuke, I guess the (old) question is actually asking for links.

Comment: @Arjan I only saw the answer, not the question. This post is closed anyways